# How do i search and print a specific cell from an excel sheet using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

i am writing java code for a library sorting project, what i want it to do is to search for a string across all cells within a specific column and then print the ones that contain the given substring, i want to do it through columns because i have a column for each piece of info about the book (author, title, ISBN), so is there a way to do this? i have written the following code so far for this (without the import statements though) and all it does is print the whole row for the book that contains a substring, i only need it to print a specific cell from that row after it selects it

```
public class testf {
 static List<Row> getRows(Sheet sheet, DataFormatter formatter, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, String searchValue) {
      List<Row> result = new ArrayList<Row>();
      String cellValue = "";
      for (Row row : sheet) {
       for (Cell cell : row) {
        cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
        if (cellValue.contains(searchValue)) {
         result.add(row);
         break;
        }
       }
      }
      return result;
     }
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InvalidFormatException {
       try
        {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\\\Users\\\\abdul\\\\Desktop\\\\University Files\\\\Object-Oriented Programming\\\\Project files\\\\Book class\\\\Books & DDC.xlsx"));

        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);


        DataFormatter formatter = new DataFormatter();
        FormulaEvaluator evaluator =  workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Row> filteredRows = getRows(sheet, formatter, evaluator, "y");

        for (Row row : filteredRows) {
         for (Cell cell : row) {
          System.out.print(formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator));
          System.out.print("\t \t");
         }
         System.out.println();
        }
        file.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the method getRows returns all the rows where there is a cell with the wanted criteria, but it doesn't tell you which cell exactly, so what you need to do is return the cells.

**getRows -> getCells**

and the code for that method will be :

```
static List<Cell> getCells(Sheet sheet, DataFormatter formatter, FormulaEvaluator evaluator, String searchValue) {
    List<Cell> result = new ArrayList<>();
    String cellValue = "";
    for (Row row : sheet) {
        for (Cell cell : row) {
            cellValue = formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator);
            if (cellValue.contains(searchValue)) {
                result.add(cell);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and as far as printing goes, you just loop through the list of cells and you pritn them normally, and if you for whatever reason need the row for a particular cell, you just call cell.getRow()

```
List<Cell> filteredCells = getCells(sheet, formatter, evaluator, "whatever");

for (Cell cell : filteredCells) {
    System.out.print(formatter.formatCellValue(cell, evaluator));
    System.out.print("\t \t");
    Row cellsRow = cell.getRow();// if you need the full row
}
```

**by the way**, I don't know about the specifications that you have, but the break that you have in your filtering method means that if a row has multiple cells with the wanted value, **you'll only get the first cell**, so be careful about that, i would recommend removing that break unless it's exactly what you want

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I settled on doing the task through full rows eventually, it made more sense that way, but I will be using your code to learn more about Apache